# I want to migrate Magento 1.7.x to magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7

Can anyone suggest a proper process to achieve migration of magento 1.7 to 2.x?
There is reference but all scattered, since many things are needed to considered and major concern includes data migration.

Comment: please watch this videos, here almost steps are explained related to migration https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KPDePFyXZI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before you start the tool installation, make sure that the version of
>   Magento 2 store and Data Migration Tool match.
>
> For example, if you are using Magento version 2.2.0, you must install
>   the Data Migration Tool version 2.2.0.

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1)  Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`

2)  Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com                                   
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
```

3)  Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

```
    1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

    2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

    3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
```

4)  Configuring the migration :-

```
    1 Change to the following directory :-
      <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

    2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
      cp config.xml.dist config.xml

    3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

    4 Specify the following at minimum:

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </source>

            <destination>

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </destination>

            <options>

            <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

            </options>
```

5)  Migrate settings :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

6)  Migrate Data :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

7)  Migrate Delta :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:delta --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

        php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Before migrating from Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.x, there are **3 things** you need to consider:

1. **Magento 1 and Magento 2 are dissimilar in many aspects**. A few differences can be listed here: file structure, built-in technologies, JavaScript library,...The migration between the two is so complicated so that you cannot just import or export it manually. If you want a do-it-yourself solution, make sure you have enough technical experience to avoid or fix any problems that may happen during the transfer including data loss or downtime on your Magento 1 store.
2. **For extensions, it cannot be moved easily in any method**. On your Magento 1, you might have used third-party extensions to add more functionality to your store. These extensions are unlikely to be compatible with Magento 2, which makes the migration of extensions hard to deal with.
3. There is no solution to migrate the theme from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x. You will need to **re-create a similar theme** to work properly with Magento 2 structure.

To migrate all data from Magento 1 to Magento 2, follow 2 steps below:

- Create a new fresh site on Magento 2.
- Migrate data on your current store from Magento 1 to Magento 2 by using an automated migration tool.

  1. Set-up Source Cart type and Target Cart type as Magento. Then enter your Magento store's URL and set up the Connector.
  2. Choose the entities you want to migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 1. Languages and order status will be matched together in order to be displayed correspondingly in the new store.
  3. Run the full migration and check the result.